# What are the factors that go into the difficulty level of drawing an anime character?

Tags: anime-production

I've noticed that in some cartoons (Batman Beyond) and anime (Hunter x Hunter, Naruto Shippuden) some characters are seen a lot, i.e. Inque in BB and Bisky in HxH.

I was thinking that some of the calculation behind that should be how easy is the character to draw.  But I'm not an artist so I wanted to know what factors make a particular character difficult to draw?

If you could explain in terms of the three anime (BB may or may not be depending on your perspective) that'd be great.

Comment: Really the characters that appear more often have a more complex drawing than the less prominent characters. Characters will not get more screen time because they are easy to draw (unless the studio has a bad budget, so not the shows you have mentioned). Also, the difficulty for each drawing style is different for everyone. Are you asking about how measurements and ratio differences between the styles affect how complex they are to draw?

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question, but as it is written right now it's a bit borderline. We don't allow questions about making your own anime/manga, but we do allow questions about how they are produced in Japan. As such, it's acceptable for people to answer with opinions of notable artists in Japan, but not from personal experience unless they've participated in anime production themselves (which I suspect no one here has). If you could edit your question to make it asking for opinions of professional anime/manga artists, that would be much better in my view.

Comment: Also, for reference, I think Batman Beyond is probably not considered anime by our definition since it was produced in the US by Warner Bros. and DC Comics, neither of which is a Japanese company. It may qualify as anime-influenced (which is sometimes allowed), but we haven't yet considered it so you'd have to ask on meta first if it's acceptable.

Comment: Every artist is different, some may have trouble with trees or female faces, while others with robots and buildings. If you wish to ask what certain manga or anime artist have trouble with, please change your question to indicated such, as this type of question can is more likely to have a definitive answer.

Comment: The biggest factor is probably detail and shading. Sometimes you'll see a poster, or promotional art of a character and see many intricate details in clothing, hair, face, and especially in the shading. When inbetweeners have to fill in all the frames that produce motion, all of the time that needs to go into drawing the detail and then shading it is increased 10-20 fold. So time and money dictate that the designs be less detailed so they are easier to animate.

Comment: @Krazer I don't really agree that "every artist is different" makes this a primarily opinion-based question. If it were restricted to notable anime/manga artists, I think it would satisfy all of the [good subjective criteria](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). However, as it is right now, it seems to be soliciting non-expert opinions, so I think it should have been closed as a "Question on making your own anime or manga".